# Print Multiple PDF file in one click

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

I want to print existing .pdf files in one click.
It works fine when i only print one file at a time, but when choose to print multiple files at once it only prints one file.

Here's my code:

```
List<string> ListFilePath; //Assume i have a collection of filepath stored here
foreach(string FilePath in ListFilePath)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = FilePath;
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", FilePath);
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.Start();
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    if (proc.HasExited == false)
    {
          proc.WaitForExit(10000);
    }

    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.Close();
}
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Does it iterate through the entire collection? Does it throw any exceptions? In the debugger, can you see it going over the process.Start() line for all the files or just the first?

Comment: yes its going over the process.Start() for all the files. When i targeted it to OneNote, the output is multiple files. But when i targeted it to Printer, it only print one file

Comment: Perhaps the problem is deeper - the PrintSpooler service. It has known issues with queuing multiple documents.

Comment: okay, i'll check into it. But from the code side, i've done nothing wrong, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is launching a process and creating a printing job on the server. Are you sure that's right, and it's not supposed to print on the client instead?

One thing you might try is to merge all pdfs into one ([PDFSharp does that nicely](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)) and then print just the merged pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Can You assign to the event handler, and stop the process then ?

Not inside this method.

Comment: so you mean i have to stop the process outside the looping ?

Comment: Right.
When the process tells You, that it is ready.
it is a suggestion.
Chech this inside the event.

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me

```
foreach (string pdf in ListFilePath)
      {
           string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdf);
           string fullPath = (@"U:\Define\Full\Path" + filename);
           Print(fullPath, 'PrinterNameHere');
      }


public static bool Print(string file, string printer)
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" +
                        @"\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe").GetValue("").ToString(),
                        string.Format("/h /t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", file, printer));
                return true;
            }
            catch 
            { return false; }
        }
```